# I have a list which contains XML strings. How can I sort this list according to one of the XML attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, string

For example:

The list is defined as:

```
List<string> listOfXML = new List<string>();
```

If this list contains 3 XML strings as given below, how can I sort this list according to "ThirdAttribute"?

XML string 1:

```
<Element>  
  <FirstAttribute>A</FirstAttribute>> 
  <SecondAttribute>B</SecondAttribute> 
  <ThirdAttribute>3</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>
```

XML string 2:

```
<Element>  
   <FirstAttribute>C</FirstAttribute>> 
   <SecondAttribute>D</SecondAttribute> 
   <ThirdAttribute>4</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>
```

XML string 3:

```
<Element>  
   <FirstAttribute>A</FirstAttribute>> 
   <SecondAttribute>B</SecondAttribute> 
   <ThirdAttribute>1</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>
```

The sorted list should have the elements in following order:

```
<Element>  
   <FirstAttribute>A</FirstAttribute>> 
   <SecondAttribute>B</SecondAttribute> 
   <ThirdAttribute>1</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>

<Element>  
  <FirstAttribute>A</FirstAttribute>> 
  <SecondAttribute>B</SecondAttribute> 
  <ThirdAttribute>3</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>

<Element>  
   <FirstAttribute>C</FirstAttribute>> 
   <SecondAttribute>D</SecondAttribute> 
   <ThirdAttribute>4</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using linq to xml you can do this:

```
orderedList = listOfXml.OrderBy(x =>(int)XElement.Parse(x).Element("ThirdAttribute"))
```

Comment: @Damith you can cast XElement directly. Value can be used too but then you need extra parsing `int.Parse(XElement.Parse(x).Element("ThirdAttribute").Value)`  this is shorter.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this ? I tried parsing through through this list of xml strings, but still I am not able to sort it.

Comment: The problem is that these 3 XML strings are stored as separate elements in a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class XmlAttributesIntComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly string elementName;

    public XmlAttributesIntComparer(string elementName)
    {
        this.elementName = elementName;
    }


    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
        doc1.LoadXml(x);

        XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();
        doc2.LoadXml(y);

        XmlText text1 = (XmlText)doc1.DocumentElement[elementName].FirstChild;
        XmlText text2 = (XmlText)doc2.DocumentElement[elementName].FirstChild;

        int attr1 = Convert.ToInt32(text1.Value);
        int attr2 = Convert.ToInt32(text2.Value);

        return attr1.CompareTo(attr2);
    }
}

// ...
listOfXML.Sort(new XmlAttributesIntComparer("ThirdAttribute"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Denis has a better answer.**

A very very very bad solution, but a solution nonetheless ...

```
List<string> listOfXML = new List<string>()
            {
               @"<Element>  
  <FirstAttribute>A</FirstAttribute>> 
  <SecondAttribute>B</SecondAttribute> 
  <ThirdAttribute>3</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>",
           @"<Element>  
   <FirstAttribute>C</FirstAttribute>> 
   <SecondAttribute>D</SecondAttribute> 
   <ThirdAttribute>4</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>",
           @"<Element>  
   <FirstAttribute>A</FirstAttribute>> 
   <SecondAttribute>B</SecondAttribute> 
   <ThirdAttribute>1</ThirdAttribute> 
</Element>"
            };

List<string> order = new List<string>();
int[] orders = new int[listOfXML.Count];

int arraylength = orders.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
{
    orders[i] = Convert.ToInt32(XElement.Parse(listOfXML[i]).Element("ThirdAttribute").Value);
}
Array.Sort(orders);

for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++)
{
    string orderedXMLString = GetXmlString(orders[i], listOfXML);
    order.Add(orderedXMLString);
}

 private static string GetXmlString(int p, List<string> listOfXML)
{
    string retXML = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in listOfXML)
    {
        if (p == Convert.ToInt32(XElement.Parse(item).Element("ThirdAttribute").Value))
        {
            retXML = item;
        }
    }
    return retXML;
}
```

A better way would be to combine all the elements into one string.
Read that combined string as XML and sort using LINQ.
Add each element from the sorted XML to a list.

Another way is to try the let keyword in LINQ to read "ThirdAttribute" value and then somehow sort accordingly:

```
var orderedXML = from elem in listOfXML
                             let o = (XElement.Parse(elem).Element("ThirdAttribute").Value)
                             select new elem and orderby here;
```

I tried this initially but couldn't go beyond the let!!!
So came up with the bad solution above.